# How to type annotate a chunker function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I try the following:

```
from typing import Iterator, List, Any, TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T')
def chunker(seq: Iterator[T], size: int) -> Iterator[List[T]]:
    for i in seq:
        yield []
for i in chunker([1, 2, 3, 4], 5):
    pass
```

However, pyright tells me that:

```
  test.py:5:18 - error: Argument of type "list[int]" cannot be assigned to parameter "seq" of type "Iterator[T@chunker]" in function "chunker"
    "list[int]" is incompatible with protocol "Iterator[T@chunker]"
      "__next__" is not present (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
1 error, 0 warnings, 0 informations
```

How should I annotate a function that takes something that you can `for i in seq` it?

I tried searching on stack and google, but I guess like my google-fu is not good enough. I could use `Union[Iterator[T], List[T]]` but I think there should be something better?

Comment: Probably with [`Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iterator is an object with state that remembers where it is during iteration. It has a `__next__` method that returns the next value in the iteration, updates the state to point at the next value and signals when it is done by raising `StopIteration`.

As you can see, a list does not have a `__next__` method:

```
>>> [1,2,3].__next__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__next__'
```

Instead, what you really want here is an iterable. An iterable is:

- anything that can be looped over (i.e. you can loop over a string or file)
- anything that can appear on the right-side of a for-loop:  `for x in iterable: ...`
- anything you can call with `iter()` that will return an iterator:  `iter(obj)`
- an object that defines `__iter__` that returns a fresh iterator

A list is indeed an iterable:

```
>>> [1,2,3].__iter__()
<list_iterator object at 0x103e68310>
```

More info can be found in this question: [What are iterator, iterable, and iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9884132/5296106)

So you should rewrite your example as:

```
from collections.abc import Generator, Iterable
from typing import Any, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
def chunker(seq: Iterable[T], size: int) -> Generator[list[T], None, None]:
    for i in seq:
        yield []
for i in chunker([1, 2, 3, 4], 5):
    pass
```

Notice that since Python version 3.9, `typing.Iterable` is deprecated. More details can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Iterable). Also, `typing.List` is a deprecated alias of `list` (more details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List)).

A simpler way is to use `Iterator` instead of `Generator` (every generator is an iterator!!):

```
from collections.abc import Iterable, Iterator
from typing import Any, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
def chunker(seq: Iterable[T], size: int) -> Iterator[list[T]]:
    for i in seq:
        yield []
for i in chunker([1, 2, 3, 4], 5):
    pass
```

Comment: Wouldn't iterator work as a return type though?

Comment: @Learningisamess you're right. Probably, a `collections.abc.Generator` is even better?

Comment: Thank you for amazing explanation. If it should return a generator, what should `Generator[list[T], what should be, here]`? For `Iterable[list[T]]` I am getting `Subscript for class "list" will generate runtime exception; enclose type annotation in quotes (Pyright)` - can this be related to that I am stuck with python3.7?

Comment: @KamilCuk If you're still using python 3.7 then you should use `typing.List`

Comment: @KamilCuk I updated my answer. You can use either `Iterator` or `Generator`